# Unable to make a field optional in Django

Tags: python, django

I have updated my Address model to make the "State" field optional by adding `blank=True` and `null=True`. I now have the following:

```
state = models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=True, null=True)
```

I ran a migration for this as well, but I am still getting the following error when the form is submitted:

```
{"errors": {"state": "This field is required."}}
```

Where else would it be marked as being a required field?

The address form has the following, do I need to remove the state reference or something?

```
class AddressForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Address
        exclude = ('customer',)

    def clean_zipcode(self):
        z = self.cleaned_data['zipcode']
        return z

    def clean_city(self):
        city = self.cleaned_data['city']
        return city

    def clean_state(self):
        state = self.cleaned_data['state']
        return state
```

Comment: The migrations do not matter. How does the form/serializer look like?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I've added more details on the form.

Comment: Why do you write `clean_zipcode`, etc. if you do not perform any cleaning?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem it's code I inherited, I haven't cleaned it up yet.

Comment: What if you `return self.cleaned_data.get('state')` instead?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I made that change and I'm still receiving the same error.